# How can I populate an input field with a .val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to edit list items that I have and I want to set the text of the parent section to the form field with `.val()`. I also want to remove it from the local storage as well, problem is I have no idea how to do this and it doesn't seem to be to popular online because I can't find it anywhere.

This is how I'm bringing in the data through the input form:

```
function addTodo(form) {
    var input = $(form).find('input[name="todo"]').first();
    if (input) {    
        var todo = input.val();
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            var todo_list = {};
            if (localStorage.todos) {
                todo_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos);
            }   
            var id = +new Date;
            todo_list[id] = {
                name: todo,
                completed: false
            };
            localStorage.todos = JSON.stringify(todo_list); 
            drawTodos();
        }   
        input.val('');
    }
    if ( jQuery.fn.validate ) {
        $(form).validate().resetForm();
    }
}
```

How would I select a list item that I've added so that it will end up back in the input feild so I can edit it?

```
<section>
            <h1>List</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="todo_list">
            <header>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="todo" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
                    <input type="submit" name="add_todo" value="Add To List" />
                </form>
            </header>
        </section>
```

I have some html generating in a loop within the jquery:

```
<section class="todo_item" id="item' + id + '"><span id="complete" class="colour complete">Complete</span><span id="incomplete" class="colour incomplete">Incomplete</span><span class="content editable" id="done">' + todo.name + '</span><a href="#" class="remove_todo"><img src="img/delete.png" /></a></section>
```

Comment: Going to need to see your HTML to make sense of this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you attach a handler to the span that has `editable` class?

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content.editable").click(function () {
        $("input[name='todo']").val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Please note, IDs must be unique. It is an error to assign the same ids: 'done', 'incomplete', 'complete' to several sections.